# How to find button element with selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code for a button :

```
   <div class="header__login">
        <button class="header__login-btn"> Login or Sign Up</button>
   </div>
```

I have tried:

```
await driver.findElement(By.css('button.header__login-btn')).click();
await driver.findElement(By.className('header__login-btn')).click();
```

Neither of these works. It did not find the button.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
await driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('button.header__login-btn')).click();
```

instead of

```
await driver.findElement(By.css('button.header__login-btn')).click();
```

Comment: tried that - By.cssSelector is not a function